# Utilización de token arroja error 3221226356

Tags: c, string, caracteres, memoria

Tengo que hacer un tp que me habilita a rendir el examen final de programación de la facultad y tengo el siguiente problema:
con la consigna:

El programa que se debe implementar en C debe tomar como entrada el tamaño de la Sopa de Letras y, las palabras que el usuario desee. Para esto debe leer, por teclado, primero el tamaño de la Sopa de Letras (la asumimos como un cuadrado, es decir, misma cantidad de filas que de columnas); luego las palabras con la orientación en la que cada una debe estar, teniendo en cuenta que:

> 0 es Horizontal de izquierda a derecha
> 1 es Horizontal de derecha a izquierda
> 2 es Vertical de arriba a bajo
> 3 es Vertical de abajo a arriba
> 4 es Diagonal de izquierda arriba a derecha abajo
> 5 es Diagonal de izquierda abajo a derecha arriba

Esto es hasta que se ingrese la palabra BASTA, la cual da por finalizado dicho ingreso.

El programa debe controlar que no se ingresen dos palabras iguales (sin importar mayúsculas y minúsculas ni orientaciones). En caso que esto se haya producido debe avisar del hecho al usuario para que
pueda seguir ingresando.

Si no comparo las palabras para ver si están repetidas, el programa cumple correctamente con los requisitos, es decir, pide palabras y orientaciones hasta que el usuario le dice que pare. Cuando agrego la parte del token, solo deja ingresar dos palabras con sus orientaciones y muestra ese error

> Process exited after 7.283 seconds with return value 3221226356.

---

```
int main() {
FILE *archivo=fopen("infoSopa.txt","a+");
if (archivo==NULL){
    printf("El archivo no se pudo abrir correctamente.");
    return 1;}
int tamanio, orientacion, cantIngresadas=0;
char* palabra, *totalPalabras, *token;
palabra = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1)); //se pide memoria para la palabra ingresada y se le 
                                                    //suma el caracter '/0'.
totalPalabras= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1)*(tamanio+1));//pide memoria para que las palabras
                                                    //como maximo ocupen todo el tablero.
token = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1)); //pide memoria para el token con el mismo criterio que la palabra.
printf("Bienvenidx a la Sopa de Letras\n");
printf("Ingrese el tama%co deseado de la Sopa de Letras:\n",164); // se utiliza el ingreso para caracteres especiales.
scanf("%d",&tamanio); //pide que se ingrese por teclado el tamaño del tablero.
fprintf(archivo,"%s","DIMENSION\n"); //imprime en el archivo el formato necesario.
fprintf(archivo,"%d \n",tamanio); //imprime en el archivo el tamaño de la sopa de letras.
fprintf(archivo,"%s","PALABRAS\n");
while((strcmp(palabra,"basta")!=0)){    // si la palabra es distinta de "basta", sigue pidiendo palabras.
    printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
    scanf(("%s"),palabra); //pide el ingreso por teclado de la palabra.
    palabra=strlwr(palabra);//pasa la palabra ingresada a minuscula para que ingresando cualquier variable de "basta", salga del bucle.
    if ((strcmp(palabra,"basta")==0)){ // si la palabra es basta, sale del bucle while. de esa manera, no pide la orientacion.
    break; //da la orden de salir del bucle si se utiliza la palabra "basta".
    }
    strcat(totalPalabras,palabra); //concatena la palabra ingresada con el puntero dedicado
                        //a almacenar todas las palabras ingresadas.
    strcat(totalPalabras,"+"); //concatena las palabras ingresadas con un simbolo '+' para que 
                        //se pueda tokenizar.
    token = strtok(totalPalabras,"+"); //crea el token, separa las palabras seguidas de un +.
    while (token!=NULL){        //bucle que determina si el token no es nulo, se sigue comparando.
    if (strcmp(token,palabra)==0){  //compara si la palabra ingresada ya está guardada en la memoria, 
                                    //si lo está, imprime la siguiente frase.
            printf("Palabra ya ingresada! \n");
                strcpy(palabra,"");
              } 
              token = strtok(NULL, "+"); //cierra el token.
    }
    printf("Ingrese un modo de orientacion de la palabra: ");
    scanf("%d",&orientacion);
    fprintf(archivo,"%s %d\n", palabra, orientacion);
    free(palabra);
    free(token);
}
fclose(archivo);
free(totalPalabras);
return 0;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hay 2 free dentro del while, y no hay 2 malloc dentro del while... con lo cual, todo se pierde, nada se recupera....

Comment: Como haces esto: palabra = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1));  sin tener un valor real de tamanio? Tu codigo, tiene muchos problemas...  tu compilador no te llena de warnings?

Answer (score 3):

**Variables sin inicializar**

C no es un lenguaje que intuya tus intenciones, más bien sigue tus órdenes al pie de la letra. Tu escribes operaciones y las mismas se ejecutan en el momento que toca, ni antes ni después.

Por ejemplo, tu solicitas una reserva de memoria y, la misma, se realizará en ese preciso momento:

```
palabra = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1));
```

Es decir, ahí se reservará espacio para `tamanio+1` caracteres. A C no le importa que no hayas inicializado esa variable, cogerá el valor que tenga en ese momento y punto. ¿Que tiene un valor negativo? Pues tu sabrás que para eso has puesto la instrucción en ese punto y no en otro más adecuado.

Es decir, primero rellena `tamanio` y luego reserva la memoria, no intentes empezar la casa por el tejado:

```
int main() {
    // Primero conocemos el tamaño del tablero
    int tamanio;
    printf("Bienvenidx a la Sopa de Letras\n");
    printf("Ingrese el tama%co deseado de la Sopa de Letras:\n",164);
    scanf("%d",&tamanio); //pide que se ingrese por teclado el tamaño del tablero.

    // Y después reservamos la memoria
    char* palabra = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1));

    // ...
```

**Memoria sin inicializar**

Con `totalPalabras` haces, al menos, tres cosas mal. La primera es la misma que lo comentado en el punto anterior, haces la reserva antes de asignar un valor válido a `tamanio`, no voy a repetirme.

La segunda es que no inicializas la memoria que acabas de reservar. Si llamas a `malloc`, el Sistema Operativo te da la cantidad de memoria pedida, pero esa memoria no está vacía, contiene datos basura que aplicaciones anteriores (o ruido, si acabas de iniciar el sistema), han ido dejando en esa memoria. Lo único que consigues con `malloc` es obtener la exclusividad del uso de esa memoria, lo demás corre de tu cuenta.

Para rellanar este array usas `strcat`. Esta función busca el finalizador de cadena `\0` para añadir la nueva palabra a continuación.

Vale, si hemos dicho que la memoria solicitada por `malloc` tiene valores aleatorios ... ¿Dónde se encontrará el primer `\0`? Cada caracter tiene 1/256 posibilidades de ser 0 ... no está mal pero no es lo que pretendes.

Puedes curarte en salud y usar `calloc` en vez de `malloc`. `calloc` inicializa todas las posiciones de la memoria a 0:

```
char* totalPalabras = (char*)calloc((tamanio+1)*(tamanio+1), sizeof(char));
```

O, más sencillo, pon un `\0` al inicio del array:

```
char* totalPalabras= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1)*(tamanio+1));
totalPalabras[0] = '\0'; // forma 1
*totalPalabras = '\0';   // forma 2
```

**Pérdida de datos**

Vamos con el segundo problema de `totalPalabras`: estás perdiendo palabras.

En efecto, es algo que estás consiguiendo por usar `strtok`. Esta función tiene el siguiente comportamiento:

- Desde el inicio del array, lo recorre hasta localizar le caracter separador
- Cuando lo encuentra lo reemplaza por `\0` y te devuelve la posición desde la que ha empezado a buscar
- En sucesivas llamadas (cuando se le pasa NULL), en vez de empezar desde el inicio del array, empieza desde donde encontró el último separador.

Es decir, `strtok` modifica el buffer original. Lo que consigues con esto es que el buscador solo funcione la primera vez.

Es más fácil verlo con un ejemplo.

Introducimos una palabra, como el buffer está vacío no hay nada que buscar y se añade la palabra

```
h  o  l  a  + \0
```

Introducimos otra palabra, `adios`. En esta ocasión salta la búsqueda, llamamos a `strtok` y se modifica el buffer (reemplazamos `+` por `\0`)

```
h  o  l  a  \0
```

Como `hola` no coincide con `adios`, se concatena y se añade el `+`:

```
h  o  l  a  a  d  i  o  s  + \0
```

Si introduces otra palabra, el comparador te intentará comparar la palabra `holaadios` con la que introduzcas. Obviamente no es el comportamiento esperado.

Lo que necesitas es un array de palabras. Podemos optar por curarnos en salud. Si cada palabra tuviese una única letra, podríamos llegar a ingresar `tamanio*tamanio` palabras, ese puede ser el límite de nuestro array de palabras:

```
char** listaPalabras = (char**)malloc(tamanio*tamanio*sizeof(char*));
int totalPalabras = 0;
```

Claro, nos hace falta una variable que nos diga cuántas palabras hemos metido en el array.

Ahora, cada vez que el usuario introduzca una palabra, lo que hacemos es añadirla en la posición del vector que le corresponda:

```
// Primero reservamos memoria para la palabra
listaPalabras[totalPalabras] = (char*)malloc((tamanio+1)*sizeof(char));

// Copiamos la palabra en el array
strcpy(listaPalabras[totalPalabras], palabra);

// Incrementamos el contador
totalPalabras++;
```

Para saber si una palabra está en el array, ahora nos basta con recorrer todas sus posiciones:

```
int existe = 0;
for( int i=0; i<totalPalabras && existe == 0; i++ )
{
    if( strcmp(palabra, listaPalabras[i]) == 0 )
        existe=1;
}

if( existe == 1 )
    // Palabra repetida
else
    // Se puede añadir la palabra
```

**Liberar la memoria**

Es muy importante liberar la memoria que hemos reservado, está bien que te acostumbres a usar `free` junto con `malloc`, `calloc` o `realloc`... pero también es crítico saber cuándo hay que liberar la memoria.

Una vez llamas a `free` deja de ser seguro acceder a la memoria, ya que la has liberado. Tienes que procurar que las llamadas a `free` se realicen cuando la memoria en cuestión ya no sea necesaria.

Fíjate que este no es tu caso:

```
palabra = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1));
token = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1));

while((strcmp(palabra,"basta")!=0)){
    // ...
    free(palabra);
    free(token);
}
```

Después de introducir la primera palabra liberas la memoria de `palabra` y de `token`. En la segunda iteración usas ambos punteros como si estuviesen apuntando a posiciones de memoria válida y no es así, ya la has liberado. Deberías mover esos `free` fuera del `while`:

```
palabra = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1));
token = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tamanio+1));

while((strcmp(palabra,"basta")!=0)){
    // ...
}

free(palabra);
free(token);
```

Y con todos estos errores creo que ya tenemos bastante para empezar. Ponte las pilas con la programación, ve poco a poco, probando el código con frecuencia y acostúmbrate a usar un IDE (CodeBlocks, QtCreator, VisualStudio, ...) y aprende igualmente a depurar el código.

Comment: Ya tienes tú ganas de escribir :-)

Comment: @Trauma estoy con algo más desesperante y esto me ha servido un poco como válvula de escape ;)

Comment: jajajaj.. estas loco... realmente loco... buena respuesta...

Comment: Genial. Antes que nada muchas gracias. 
Estoy usando dev c/c++ ya que no pude hacer funcionar C en Visual Studio, me da error al compilar.
Por otro lado, tengo otra version del programa que desisti de usarla porque era demasiado compleja sin sentido. Ahora, cuando hacia el mismo procedimiento con el token, lo que lograba era individualizar las palabras y compararlas bien digamos y no como el "holaadios". -
Me resulta muy interesante la solucion de hacerlo con una array, pero la verdad es que no tenia ni idea cómo. 
Te agradezco nuevamente y perdoname por las manqueadas.

Comment: termino la idea aca: soy ingresante de la facultad en 2020, no tuvimos ni una clase de C y las practicas eran super sencillas... se me quemaron los papeles al tratar de hacer ese programa. Por eso mismo valoro tu tiempo y deciación al contestar todas mis dudas/problemas.

Comment: @BrunoPace Dev es un IDE antiguo y sin mantenimiento. Te sugiero usar herramientas más modernas y actuales, como pudiera ser codeblocks. Agradezco tus comentarios.

Comment: @Trauma ya lo tienes. Hice la pregunta, no la respuesta, lo mismo por eso no la localizabas